# Represent JSON in strongly typed POCO class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a POCO class in C# that represents a JSON object:

**class**

```
public int id {get; set;}
public string name {get; set;}
public string description {get; set;}
```

**JSON**

```
{ 
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "name",
    "description" : "description"
}
```

Now the json is going to have these properties added:

```
{
    "property_1" : "value_1",
    "property_2" : "value_2",
    "property_3" : "value_3"
//etc
}
```

There could be as few as 0 properties and as many as needed but they would all be named `property_` and a number. 
So for the class I want to have a `List<>` of some sort instead of hard coding each property individually, but then went returning the `Json` object (I'm using MVC) I want to split that `List<>` into individual objects, how can I do that?

Instead of having:

```
return Json(property_1, property_2, property_3);
```

I want:

```
return Json(properties.Split());
```

Comment: Just curious, why would you not use collections/name-value-pairs for these, both as server side objects and represented as JSON?

Comment: @Moby'sStuntDouble The json object is being consumed by a webservice and that is how it has the properties setup, I cant control it.

Comment: please slap the person who made the web service from me, on your behalf :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Json.NET for your JSON serialization, you can use the `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute to capture properties which you have not coded for. Starting with Json.NET 5.0.8, this property affects both serialization and deserialization to ensure your POCO objects support round-tripping.

In practice, I placed this attribute on a field in an abstract base class which all of my model classes are derived from:

[`ExtensibleJsonObject`](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/blob/master/src/corelib/Core/Domain/ExtensibleJsonObject.cs)

Comment: That's very interresting! It should open up some interresting possibilities. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom [`MediaTypeFormatter`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) and insert it to your HttpConfiguration.Formatters collection in front of the standard JsonFormatter, or extend the standard one and replace it entirely. (I'd suggest the former.)

The MediaTypeFormatters give you access to the raw stream as it's comming in, and you can basically do whatever you want with both serialization and deserialization at that point using all of JSON.NET.